# typoscript 3 level menu

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

i need specific menu for typo3: list all pages of all levels, like this:
level 1 page 1 -- level 2 page 1 -- level 3 page 1
level 1 page 1 -- level 2 page 1 -- level 3 page 2
level 1 page 1 -- level 2 page 1 -- level 3 page 3
level 1 page 1 -- level 2 page 1 -- level 3 page n
level 1 page 1 -- level 2 page 2 -- level 3 page 1
level 1 page 1 -- level 2 page 2 -- level 3 page 2
level 1 page 1 -- level 2 page 2 -- level 3 page n
level 1 page 2 -- level 2 page 1 -- level 3 page 1
level 1 page 2 -- level 2 page 1 -- level 3 page 2
level 1 page 2 -- level 2 page 1 -- level 3 page n
level 1 page 3 -- level 2 page 1 -- level 3 page 1
...

something like a table of breadcrumbs but visible on each page level.

Comment: the problem will be to build a breadcrumb (rootline) to any page. This (`HMENU` with `special = rootline`) is not available in typoscript by default for another page than the current.

Comment: i know that breadcrumb - (special = rootline) will not work, so maybe there is another approach?

Comment: you might use the VH from ext:vhs [`<v:page.breadcrumb id="{uid}" />`](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Page/BreadCrumbViewHelper.html)